# dados não ordenados depois da execução C

Tags: c, algoritmo, classificação

Preciso colocar as colunas a em ordem, porém, apenas os nomes estão ficando ordenados corretamente. As funções que ordenam as notas e o sexo não estão dando certo. Alguém pode me indicar onde estou errando? Os exercícios não exige que as relações continuem as mesmas, apenas ordenar os dados

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define LIN 31
#define COL 50

    

void ordena(char nomes[LIN][COL]);
void ordenaIdade(int idade[LIN]);
void ordenaNota(float nota[LIN]);
void ordenaSexo(char sexo[LIN]);

int main(){
    
    int i;
    char nomes[LIN][COL] = {
        "Pedro Andrade Schmitz                   ",
        "João Manoel Spingler Francisco (Juvenil)",
        "Gustavo Andrade Schmitz                 ",
        "Maria Clara Argolo Sampaio              ",
        "Arthur Marinho Miranda                  ",
        "Jose Gomes da Silva                     ",
        "Pedro Castro Cabral (Juvenil)           ",
        "Davi Guilherme                          ",
        "Bruno Petri                             ",
        "Isabela Miranda Lima                    ",
        "Sebastian Annanias De Araujo Solari     ",
        "Robson Andre Da Paz Radmann             ",
        "Tomas Levy                              ",
        "Facundo Nicolas Mezquita Duarte         ",
        "Gustavo Gouvea Oliva                    ",
        "Raphaela Mello Oka                      ",
        "Anderson Calado Schmitt                 ",
        "Pedro Eckschmidt Buso                   ",
        "Felix Dumas                             ",
        "Danilo Gilberto Volkmann Gonçalves      ",
        "Pedro Henrique Colauto Gregorio         ",
        "Marcelo Augusto Evangelista Ribeiro     ",
        "Piedro Xavier Tuchtenhagen              ",
        "Beatriz Vilela Da Silva                 ",
        "Erik Kai Attie                          ",
        "Arthur Poliselli Farsky                 ",
        "Felipe Toledo Piza Abramento            ",
        "Luca Suplicy Leger                      ",
        "Matheus Mello Oka                       ",
        "Wesley Patrick Guedes De Oliveira       ",
        "Yan Ewald Zechner                       "
        
    };
    char sexo[LIN] = {'M','M','M','F','M','M','M','M','M','F','M','M','M','M','M','F','M','M','M','M','M','M','M','F','M','M','M','M','M','M','M'};
    int idade[LIN] = {15,14,15,17,16,17,18,14,15,14,15,18,14,15,16,16,15,14,14,16,17,15,18,14,14,14,15,16,17,18,14};
    float nota1[LIN] = {7.0,2.0,5.0,7.0,7.8,5.0,7.0,9.8,7.4,8.5,7.0,9.0,8.4,8.0,7.0,6.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,7.0,6.0,7.0,7.0,5.0,4.5,6.0,8.0,7.0,9.0,10.0,8.0};
    float nota2[LIN] = {9.0,0.0,7.0,6.0,7.0,9.0,8.0,7.0,10.0,8.0,8.0,8.4,7.0,9.0,5.0,5.4,9.0,6.5,9.0,6.0,4.0,6.5,8.0,9.0,7.0,7.7,8.0,7.0,9.0,10.0,6.0};
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    
    for(i=0;i<LIN;i++){
        printf("%s\t%c\t%d\t%.1f\t%.1f\n",nomes[i],sexo[i],idade[i],nota1[i],nota2[i]);
    }
    
    ordena(nomes);
    ordenaSexo(sexo);
    ordenaIdade(idade);
    ordenaNota(nota1);
    ordenaNota(nota2);
    
    printf("\n|==========NOMES ORDENADOS==========|\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<LIN;i++){
        printf("%s\t%c\t%d\t%.1f\t%.1f\n",nomes[i],sexo[i],idade[i],nota1[i],nota2[i]);
    }
    
    
    
    printf("\n\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void ordena(char nomes[LIN][COL]){
    int i,j,k;
    char aux[COL];
    
    for(i=0;i<LIN;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<LIN;j++){
            k=strcmp(nomes[i],nomes[j]);
            if(k>0){
                strcpy(aux,nomes[i]);
                strcpy(nomes[i],nomes[j]);
                strcpy(nomes[j],aux);
            }
        }
    }
}


void ordenaIdade(int idade[LIN]){
    int i,j,aux;
    
    for(i=1;i<LIN;i++){
        aux = idade[i];
        j = i-1;
        idade[0] = aux;
        while (aux < idade[j]){
            idade[j+1] = idade[j];
            j--;
        }
        idade[j+1] = aux;
    }
}

void ordenaNota(float nota[LIN]){
    int i,j,aux;
    
    for(i=1;i<LIN;i++){
        aux = nota[i];
        j = i-1;
        nota[0] = aux;
        while (aux < nota[j]){
            nota[j+1] = nota[j];
            j--;
        }
        nota[j+1] = aux;
    }
}
    
void ordenaSexo(char sexo[LIN]){
        int i,j,k;
        char aux;
    
            for(j=i+1;j<LIN;j++){
                if(strcmp(sexo[i],sexo[i+1])>0){
                    aux = sexo[i];
                    sexo[i] = sexo[i+1];  
                    sexo[i+1] = aux; 
                }
            }
        
}
```

Comment: Pelo que consegui entender cada índice de cada um dos arrays identifica uma pessoa e seus atributos (nomes[i] é o nome da i-ésima pessoa, sexo[i] seu sexo, idadei] sua idade e nota1[i] e nota2[i] suas notas) dessa forma você não pode ordenar separadamente cada array pois perderá a associação de cada pessoa com seus atributos. Ao definir que tem que trocar de posição dos nomes **tem** que trocar a posição dos atributos a eles associados.

Comment: Na verdade no exercício não exige manter as relações, apenas ordenar os dados, mesmo que as relações sejam perdidas

Comment: Em minha opinião você entendeu de forma errada a formulação do problema pois sua afirmação não faz o menor sentido e, creio, nenhum professor cometeria tamanha idiotice.

Comment: Apesar de que em C uma string ser um array de caracteres seguido do caractere terminador '\0' o seu array sexo não é uma string e sim um simples array de caracteres e portanto a comparação de cada caractere não deve ser feita com o uso da função strcmp (diferentemente de nomes).

Comment: as 3 ultimas funçoes de ordenar só tem 1 for em cada... compara essas 3 com a primeira função que vc vai encontrar o erro... e na hora de comparar o sexo compare com > e não com strcmp

Answer (score 1):

- Na primeira Função, das notas

```
void ordenaNota(float nota[LIN]){
   int i,j,aux; //O aux aqui tinha que ser float, assim como seu vetor nota, do contrário nenhuma das operações com ele funcionará
   
   for(i=1;i<LIN;i++){
       aux = nota[i];
       j = i-1;
       nota[0] = aux; //Não compreendi essa linha, como ela sempre vai ser executada, a primeira posição do vetor não será sempre trocada pelo valor a ser analisado? significando que em LIN-1 vezes vc terá pelo menos 2 repetições do mesmo valor
       while (aux < nota[j]){
           nota[j+1] = nota[j]; // Essa linha somada com a outra fará vc simplesmente copiar o dado para as posições em que aux for menor, posso estar errado, mas acredito que essa função vai entrar em loop infinito
           j--;
       }
       nota[j+1] = aux;
   }
}
```

- Uma estratégia melhor para a função de ordenar notas é que a que você já aplicou na Ordena normal, um BubbleSort simples. Caso queira executar algo mais semelhante com o que vem pensado, sugiro estudar o código do InsertSort, que tem uma abordagem similar.
- Na função de Ordenar sexo, creio que o char precise ter um tamanho definido, no seu caso, [1] bastaria.

Espero ter ajudado.